# Why Assets.xcassets increases PNG files

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, xcode6

The size of my file Bla.png = 448kb. I created an archive Product > Archive and it turned out that it was my file Bla.png = 927kb! How do I prevent Xcode modify PNG files?

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38902031/xcode-blowing-up-png-size-and-ignoring-compress-png-no-flag ? – Are you really still using Xcode 6? Does the problem also occur with an up-to-date version?

Comment: @Martin R   Xcode Version 8.1

Comment: Is there a way to fix this for PNGs in an xcassets folder? The ability to change type in the inspector only appears to be available for files outside of .xcassets.